# C++ Implementation of the GDAL Algorithm GDALFillNodata()

Tags: python, c++, raster, gdal

Looking for some help with some C++ code to implement/call the GDALFillNoData() algorithm.  I already have a working version using python and gdal, which is somewhat slow filling elevation DEMs (1.5GB).  I'm curious if this is possible.  I've written the code for a command line application and posted it here.  File paths are hard coded at the moment.  It builds (CodeBlocks 16.1/MinGW) and runs in but then crashes.

I'm not a C++ programmer, though I wish I were, but I'm trying to understand the language better.  I'm moderately decent at python.  I'm likely missing some thing basic here that's normal to C++.

There likely code that's been commented out through testing.  So if something doesn't make sense that's why.

Here's the Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gdal.h"
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "cpl_conv.h"
#include "gdal_alg.h"

int main()
{
    GDALAllRegister();
    //CPLPushErrorHandler(CPLQuietErrorHandler);

    // Read/Write Files
    const char *input = "D:/myIn.tif";

    GDALDataset *pSrcDataset;
    //GDALRasterBandH hMaskBand;
    GDALRasterBand  *poBand;
    //CPLErr maskBand;
    int maskFlags;
    int noData;
    double maxSearch = 10.0;
    int maxInt = 1;
    int nBlockXSize, nBlockYSize;
    double adfGeoTransform[6];
    //CPLErr eErr;

    pSrcDataset = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpen(input, GA_Update);
    CPLAssert( pSrcDataset != NULL );

    poBand = pSrcDataset->GetRasterBand( 1 );
    poBand->GetBlockSize( &nBlockXSize, &nBlockYSize );
    printf( "Block=%dx%d Type=%s, ColorInterp=%s\n",
           nBlockXSize, nBlockYSize,
           GDALGetDataTypeName(poBand->GetRasterDataType()),
           GDALGetColorInterpretationName(
           poBand->GetColorInterpretation()) );

    noData = pSrcDataset->GetRasterBand(1)->GetNoDataValue();
    printf( "No Data Value = %i\n",noData );

    printf( "Driver: %s/%s\n",
           pSrcDataset->GetDriver()->GetDescription(),
           pSrcDataset->GetDriver()->GetMetadataItem( GDAL_DMD_LONGNAME ) );

    printf( "Size is %dx%dx%d\n",
           pSrcDataset->GetRasterXSize(), pSrcDataset->GetRasterYSize(),
           pSrcDataset->GetRasterCount() );

    if( pSrcDataset->GetProjectionRef()  != NULL )
        printf( "Projection is `%s'\n", pSrcDataset->GetProjectionRef() );

    if( pSrcDataset->GetGeoTransform( adfGeoTransform ) == CE_None )
        printf( "Origin = (%.6f,%.6f)\n", adfGeoTransform[0], 
               adfGeoTransform[3] );
        printf( "Pixel Size = (%.6f,%.6f)\n",adfGeoTransform[1], 
               adfGeoTransform[5] );

    //maskBand = pSrcDataset->GetRasterBand(1)->GetMaskBand();

    //hMaskBand = GDALGetMaskBand( maskBand );
    //hMaskBand = pSrcDataset->GetRasterBand(1)->GetNoDataValue();
    maskFlags = pSrcDataset->GetRasterBand(1)->GetMaskFlags();
    printf ( "Mask Flags = %i\n", maskFlags );

    printf ( "Processing image\n" );

    // Ignore that this is on two lines here
    GDALFillNodata(pSrcDataset, pSrcDataset->GetRasterBand(1)- 
    >GetMaskBand(), maxSearch, 0, maxInt, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
    //CPLAssert( eErr == CE_None);

    GDALClose(pSrcDataset);

    return 0;
}
```

Some errors that I'm getting when running this code (see image links).  The process returns a 255 which is I think something that is unique to CodeBlocks?

[Program Crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezEBA.jpg)

[Process returns 255](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqV7b.jpg)

Here is the python implementation.  Pretty straight forward.  Is None the same as NULL?  Because one of the errors I got when using NULL as the hMaskBand ([rasterfill.cpp](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/alg/rasterfill.cpp))

```
#Run the gdal fill
    ET = gdal.Open(infile, GA_Update)
    ETband = ET.GetRasterBand(1)

    result = gdal.FillNodata(targetBand = ETband, maskBand = None, 
    maxSearchDist = 500, smoothingIterations = 1)

    print result # return 0

    ET = None
```

Please let me know if you need more information.  Knowing what little I know about C++ it's probably my build environment.  :)

Thanks,
Heath

Comment: The first argument of GDALFillNoData should be a raster band, not the dataset. Is it just a typo?

Comment: Yes, yes it should be a raster band just like it says in the documentation.   Jeez!  It's always the simplest thing.  Thanks for your help @GabriellaGiordano!.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up for the comments above, the problem is the fact that the first argument given to the [GDALFillNoData API](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716151832/http://www.gdal.org:80/gdal__alg_8h.html#a0a079afef61968f224b159d48423d1c6) is a GDALDataset* instead of a GDALRasterBand*.

But I've been struggling too much with GDAL to keep myself from giving a much explanatory answer.

The implementation of the GDAL lib is very C oriented, while it is indeed written using C++ features (e.g. classes).
So, you will find that in many of the available APIs the arguments are not referring to types defined in the library. Instead, they use typedef like the [GDALRasterBandH](https://gdal.org/api/index.html#raster-api#aeef8194c3ad5f1ed6ca27ea4cce24685), that are indeed alias to the void* type.

This has the nasty effect that, whatever type of argument you feed to the compiler, it won't complain, hence you will get a lot of errors at runtime if you make such (very common) mistakes.

Why they do this? I think it was a way to exploit [PIMPL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) in order to avoid the compiler to work on several **translation units**, every time one of this classes was modified.

The real problem of this approach is that you lose all the benefits from  [static type checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system), i.e. the compiler telling you when there is a type mismatch. As a side note, this is not a critics to the GDAL lib (thank God we have it!! And it is a huge and very useful project), it's just the way it is.

By the way, I'm currently working on a C++ opensource project, [Rasterix](https://github.com/mogasw/rasterix/), that is meant to be a user friendly GUI to GDAL tools for raster datasets. Do not take it as *do it like me* hint, as this app still needs proper testing, but there is a lot of GDAL APIs use cases there that may help if you need sort of examples on how to use them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I was some what confused with the GDALRasterBandH...and the documentation was vague.  GDAL is an amazing library!  And is so capable.   I'll check out the Rasterix.  The GUI is really sharp.  Thanks again.  Will be updating this code soon.

Comment: Thank you for trying it. Any feedback is appreciated :) feel free to submit comments or issues through GitHub, should you find some problem. We will update the docs very soon.